# 正規表現で "月日" を表す文字列から末尾以外の0を削除したい

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

末尾の0でない0を削除したいのですが、`/[^0$]0/` こうすると0と直前の文字を削除してしまいます。`/^(?!0$)0/` こちらも試しましたが、マッチしませんでした。

```
'12/09'.replace(/[^0$]0/, '') // この場合は0を削除したい
'12/10'.replace(/[^0$]0/, '') // この場合はしたくない

replace(/^(?!0$)0/, '')
```

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

月日を表す文字列の日付部分だけ、一桁の数なら二桁目の `0` を消したいということでしょうか。

であれば、`/` の直後が `0` であれば `0` を削除すれば良さそうです。

```
'12/09'.replace(/\/0/, '/');  // ==> '12/9'
'12/10'.replace(/\/0/, '/');  // ==> '12/10'
'01/02'.replace(/\/0/, '/');  // ==> '01/2'
```

月の部分も消したいのであれば、数字部分を認識して上桁のゼロを消すのはどうでしょうか。

```
'12/09'.replace(/0+(?=[0-9])/g, '');  // ==> '12/9'
'12/10'.replace(/0+(?=[0-9])/g, '');  // ==> '12/10'
'01/02'.replace(/0+(?=[0-9])/g, '');  // ==> '1/2'
```

<sup># この正規表現を別の目的で使いたい方へ：このままだと `1001` は `11` になるので注意してください。</sup>

Comment: 忘れていましたが、月の0も対応したかったので助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 7):

こういうこと？

```
'12/01'.replace(/\b0+/, '')
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。シンプルでしたね...

Answer (score 3):

日付を表す文字列の月と日から先頭の `0` を取り除く場合は、以下の様な方法も考えられます。

```
(new Date('12/09')).toLocaleDateString().slice(5,)
=> 12/9
(new Date('12/10')).toLocaleDateString().slice(5,)
=> 12/10
(new Date('01/01')).toLocaleDateString().slice(5,)
=> 1/1
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

これで動きますか？

```
'12/09'.replace(/^(.+\/)0+(\d+)$/, '$1$2')
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。動きました。